# How to implement Server Object in Swagger Document?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

I am new in swagger. My requirement is to add server objects in swagger json. Following is a sample servers object:

```
servers:
- url: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/
```

Do we need to configure something to the `AddSwaggerGen()` in startup.cs file for achieving this?

Or is there any configuration options to set server URL and where we can specify multiple server URLs for different environments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do it when configuring the Swagger middleware with `UseSwagger` method  like below:

```
app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    options.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swagger, httpReq) =>
    {
        swagger.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>
        {
            // You can add as many OpenApiServer instances as you want by creating them like below
            new OpenApiServer
            {
                // You can set the Url from the default http request data or by hard coding it
                // Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}",
                Url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5", 
                Description = "Open Weather Map"
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I searched for a while how to programmatically configure swagger and this answer helped me a lot. From `swagger.` I can access entire OpenApi object. Thanks!